# .htaccess trying to hide subdirectory - one solution works, the other does now, why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am hiding a subfolder in the URLs for a website

was:

```
https://www.example.com/sub-folder/index.php
```

want:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php
```

In the "sub-folder" there is the following in the .htaccess, one works and the other does not, and I do not understand why.

this works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sub-folder/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

This DOES NOT work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub-folder/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub-folder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

The latter appears to be correct. I admit it! I copied this latter one from another stackoverflow solution, which appeared to work. According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be the latter yields the correct result, but in practise it does not work.

I have a working solution with the former, but do not understand why the latter fails. Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to ... the latter yields the correct result, but in practise it does not work.

Because that testing tool *assumes* your `.htaccess` file is in the document root, not in `/sub-folder`.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^sub-folder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
> ```

This rule will never match when the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/sub-folder` itself, because the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is less the directory-prefix. The directory-prefix is the filesystem path of where the `.htaccess` file is located (which includes the trailing slash).

So, when you request `/sub-folder/foo/bar` the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in `/sub-folder/.htaccess` matches against `foo/bar` (the requested URL-path, less the directory-prefix).

Whereas, when you request `/sub-folder/foo/bar` the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in `/.htaccess` matches against `sub-folder/foo/bar` (the requested URL-path, less the directory-prefix).

Comment: Ok, thanks, that now makes sense. Then %{THE_REQUEST} is unmodified and therefore would contains any sub-folders from the "original" URL.

Comment: And if I read the documentation completely:

```The directory path where the rule is defined is stripped from the currently mapped filesystem path before comparison (up to and including a trailing slash). The net result of this per-directory prefix stripping is that rules in this context only match against the portion of the currently mapped filesystem path "below" where the rule is defined.```

Comment: Yes, `THE_REQUEST` actually contains the first line of the HTTP request headers. eg. `GET /sub-folder/index.php HTTP/1.1` and is _unmodified_ as you say. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, regardless of where the `.htaccess` file is located. But note that this does get updated when URLs are internally rewritten (not the case here).